# baking normal from procedural causes odd scretching around different materials

Tags: materials, normals, procedural

I have a mesh with three different materials. I applied different procedurals to each. When baking the diffuse texture give me no problems, but the normal maps are giving me strange stretch patterns around where the materials change.(I will post the file if someone will tell me how, but for now, on the image is the set up of one of my procedural normals with its result in the top two images. The bottom two images show the generated normal image and how it looks on the model.)

(someone let me know : [image]

(You will have to hit the bake button as apparently the downloaded version decided it would be great to make the image blank- thanks blender.)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NglD0.jpg

Comment: hello maybe share the part you are trying to bake

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean. You're looking at it. It's a procedural normal texture applied to the part of the mesh you see. If you mean I should provide the file, again, how do I do that?

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Comment: Thanks, one of the things I wanted to know was that. Figure the image would only go so far.

Comment: @ZackHound Just go to `File` > `External Data` > `Automatically Pack Resources` on your .blend file to ship the files with the file automatically and now when you upload your file, we will have access to your images/textures :)

Comment: It unbaked the image, but just hit the bake button and it should give you the normal I'm getting. Sorry, ya'll know blender is finiky.

Comment: I mean I did what you said, but it still unbaked the image.